# How to calculate the exponent?

Tags: c++

I am trying to calculate the exponent in this code and it give me inf

```
int num;
float term , sum=0;
cout<<"Please enter the number"<<endl;
cin>>num;
for(int i=1 ;i<=100;i++){
term=pow(num,i)/factorial(i);
cout<<term<<" ";
sum=sum+term;

 cout<<"Sum ="<<sum<<endl;

int factorial(int n)

  if(n > 1)
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
 else
     return 1;
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve]

Comment: pow(x, 100) looks suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

1-pow(num,i)/factorial(i)
this is integer division so you should convert it into real division
you can make the function returns double so the division will work properly.
2-int factorial(int n)
we said above make it double so the division will work properly
but making it double is not enough to fix the problem
some factorial are huge so double can't represent it 
so make it long double.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code uses **integer division** where e.g. `7/3` → `2`, exactly. You need to instead use **floating point division**, where `7.0/3.0` → `2.3333`..., approximately. In C++ the kind of division is governed by the types of the operands: if both are of integer type you get integer division.

Second, you need to consider the **number ranges** of intermediate results. In particular *n*! is a pretty big number for even quite small *n*. By considering multiplying *n*! with itself reversed you know that *n*!² > *n*<sup>*n*</sup>, in general, and that's quite explosive growth. Google search's built-in calculator says that 100! = 9.332622⋅10^157.

With the usual `float` as 32-bit IEEE type, its maximum is roughly 3.4⋅10^38, so you need to use `double` *if* you're going to calculate that factorial directly.

Another reason to use `double` is that it's the default floating point type in C++, e.g. `3.14` is of type `double`.

An alternative, that permits you to still use `float`, is to calculate each new term by simple adjustment of the previous term. This is also far more efficient. But consider using `double` even if `float` could do the job: you get better precision, and you're then not misleadingly telling a reader of the code that there's some special reason to use `float`.